Installed new rim and hubs. Disc rotor is now rubbing against disc brake mount
The new hubs spacing seemed to be too small for the fork that it now rubs against the disc brake mount. In the picture, I can't even squeeze it in between the mounting point and the rotor.
Looking for solutions or workarounds. Steel fork of a 20' (406) minivelo.
I actually thought of installing the mount on the other side but the disc caliper would be too far offset and there  doesn't seem to be a mounting adaptor for that.

enter image description here



Are you sure the rotor is mounted correctly on the hub? It is fairly easy to install it the wrong way round.

@Erlkoenig wrong way around? you mean flipped? Why would that matter? the rotor is pretty flat, I don't see why that would change anything. (still I will try to do that first thing tomorrow because Im running out of options).

Yes, I mean flipped. It matters very much because the rotor is not centered on the mounting "ring" and also the rotor is optimized to transfer the braking force in just one direction, I.e. it is even a safety issue.

Better also take a photo of the rotor with the wheel removed from the frame. Btw, what kind of axle is that?

@Erlkoenig I see. I had it mounted the same way it was before. It's a quick release.

@Erlkoenig https://i.imgur.com/cq2JXWM.jpeg rotor with the wheel removed from the frame.

Thanks, I missed that it's a 6-bolt-rotor. Looks fine.

Considering amount of QR axle thread is showing, something is not right with hub spacing. Maybe axle adapters are incorrect.
